# Login screen dismissed and reappears on failed login

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

The initial view controller for my app is HomeView, which displays information important to the user.  If a user is not logged in, the user interface will present the LoginView view controller prompting a user to login.

The issue is when the user puts incorrect login credentials, hits login, the app presents an error.  Once the error is cleared, the app dismisses the LoginView then presents the LoginView again.  The behavior should just be the alert then leave the LoginView up.

1) From HomeView (initial view controller)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if (PFUser.currentUser()?.username == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView")

            //self.showViewController(viewController, sender: self)

            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
    }
}
```

2) From LoginView verification of user credentials and then login attempt with parse.

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = usernameField.text?.lowercaseString

    let password = passwordField.text

    if username == "" || password == "" {

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password")

    } else if username?.characters.count < 5 {

        self.displayAlert("Failed Signup", message: "Username must be greater than 5 characters")

    } else if password?.characters.count < 8 {

        self.displayAlert("Failed Signup", message: "Password must be greater than 8 characters")

    } else {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))

        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center

        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray

        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            //Kill spinner
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if ((user) != nil) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeView")

                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

            } else {

                self.displayAlert("Failed Signup", message: "\(error)")

            }
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT:

3) displayAlert Function

```
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    })))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I should note that my home view controller is part of a SWRevealViewController with a sidebar menu.  The navigation controller for the SWRevealViewController as the initial view controller

Comment: Can you post your `displayAlert` function?

Comment: @pbush25 Edited the question to add the displayAlert function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the call to `self.dismissViewController` in the completion for your button. That's what tells the app to dismiss the login view. When designing alerts where you only have an error and you want the dismiss button to remove the alert, you don't have to put any code in the completion.